# PhoneGap - Android - swipe navigation in phonegap

Tags: android, html, jquery-mobile, cordova

I'm making an phonegap app for the android platform. In this app i want swipe navigation within multiple html pages. Please tell me how i can do this.
Either it is done in single html page or i've to create multiple html page for this swipe navigation.

Thanks In Advance.
preet

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are using jquery mobile then it is easy to do that because jquery support swipe,swipeleft and swiperight touch event.

**swipe**

A swipe event, triggered when the user swipes either vertically (20 or fewer pixels)
or horizontally (30 or more pixels)

**swipeleft**

A left-directed swipe, triggered when the user swipes to the left 30 or more pixels

**swiperight**

A right-directed swipe, triggered when the user swipes to the right 30 or more pixels

use this:

```
<script>
$("ul").delegate("li", "swipe", function() {
 // The user has swiped to the right on a list view item. Show an edit menu.
$(this).find(".menu-edit").show();
})
</script>
```